# How can one send Firebase Analytics events from a Winforms .Net application?

Tags: .net, firebase, google-analytics

It seems the [Windows SDK for Google Analytics](https://github.com/dotnet/windows-sdk-for-google-analytics) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238405.aspx) are out of date as Google Analytics now requires the use of Firebase for mobile/non-web apps.

I am aware of [FireSharp](https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp) and other .Net wrappers for Firebase, but I am not aware of any way to log analytics events as per the android [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events) from a .Net Windows application.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up simulating a web page via the web app route in the end.

Comment: Sad that this is the only way to set up analytics for a windows app... But, what can you do?